# How to destroy the subprocess of Java Process

Tags: java, linux, shell

I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` to execute command `tail -f filename | grep str` which is based on OS pipe. I managed to achieve my business logic. But still there is a problem I must solve:
When using pipe, the Process will for another process for tail command:

```
$ ps -ef | grep test.log
admin     6953 32721  0 16:32 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c tail -f /home/admin    
/test.log | unbuffer -p grep '1444379575648'
admin     6957  6953  0 16:32 ?        00:00:00 tail -f /home/admin/test.log
```

`Process.destroy()` method destroys itself(**pid:6953**) only.How can I destroy its `subprocess(pid:6957)` in my Java program?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`, use 2 `ProcessBuilder`s to explicitly build the individual processes, and connect their inputs and outputs together to do the equivalent of the piping.

Then you will a separate `Process` object for each, and can kill them as you please.

Comment: that is a good suggestion,but may it have an Negative effect on the performance of the process?

Comment: Performance should only be a consideration after functionality: if you need the PID of a process and you can't get it, your performance is infinitely bad in that it doesn't do the right thing.

Comment: you mean that there is not a way to get the pid of the Process?

Comment: If you have created a `Process` for each, you don't need to know the PID of the actual processes: you have the `Process` instances that you can call `destroy` on.

Answer (score 0):

i found another way:

```
public static final String getPid() {
    try {
        RuntimeMXBean runtimeBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        String name = runtimeBean.getName();
        int k = name.indexOf('@');
        if (k > 0)
            return name.substring(0, k);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

This works on linux,win,mac.

Comment: Sorry, which process' PID is this supposed to return?

Comment: After getting the pid of the subprocess,how can i destroy the process?

Comment: You'd need to do something platform-specific, like execute a `kill` command on linux, `killtask` on windows etc. All the more reason to use `ProcessBuilder/Process`, since that abstracts the platform-specific details for you.

Comment: Ok,anyway,one solutionin some kind ,but it may make my code smell bad in my opinion. thanks